# Why isnt my SVG image showing up in my web browser?

Tags: html, css, svg

So I have an SVG image which acts as a swirl effect and sits on top of the menu div tag my bottom menu of my website.

It previews fine in Dreamweaver but when I go to publish this, it doesn't show.

This is a simple copy and paste from Adobe illustrator and it's worked perfectly before, until tonight when I decided it not going to show in the web browser. I use Edge.

I expect the SVG image to show in the web browser, but it doesn't show.

Any ideas?

```html
<svg id="bdff17f9-6220-4e90-95a0-392adfab69fd" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 835.69 184.37">
<defs>
<style>
.a1a6fb66-4b89-4bb7-b5cb-a0c76572bf56{fill:url(#b55c1108-0f51-4b65-83b4-456351451c95);}
</style>
<linearGradient id="b55c1108-0f51-4b65-83b4-456351451c95" x1="0.63" y1="259.63" x2="836.32" y2="259.63" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop offset="0" stop-color="#22205f"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#22205f"/></lineargradient>
</defs>
<title>two-layer-swirl</title>
<path class="a1a6fb66-4b89-4bb7-b5cb-a0c76572bf56" d="M836.32,225.39V351.81H.63V225.39C360.33,65.41,449,295,836.32,225.39Z" transform="translate(-0.63 -167.45)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: The code snippet doesn't show any SVG for you?

Comment: By "in the browser" could that mean when you've uploaded it to a website where possibly the host doesn't support the SVG MIME Type? Or just trying to open it locally in a browser? Because it displays fine here.

Comment: The file is not valid as a standalone file as the closing linearGradient is written as lineargradient i.e. all lowercase.